# X11 Dependency, Compile Dbus without X11, starting only Shell C++ Applications Raspbian Linux

Tags: linux, shell, x11, dbus, raspbian

Hello Dear SO Community :)

I am trying to get  DBus working on my Raspberry Pi.
The example code from libdbus-c++-1 is working fine when i am in the Pi Desktop environment -> (startx)

My researches on the internet and the examples i found on stackoverflow didnt help me :[.

However, when i am in the Shell-Mode i get the error message

```
./client
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'DBus::Error'
  what():  /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
Aborted
```

i also tried

```
eval 'dbus-launch --auto-syntax' ./client

eval 'dbus-launch --auto-syntax' ./server
```

but it does not work, the server app is starting a message daemon but it is not reachable from the client. Also the daemon stays active.

i got:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'DBus::Error'
  what():  The name org.freedesktop.DBus.Examples.Echo was not provided by any .service files
call1: Aborted
```

also it does not shown in the services list.

after this i tried another command

```
DISPLAY=":0" DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" ./server
```

and i got:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'DBus::Error'
  what():  Connection ":1.10" is not allowed to own the service "org.freedesktop.DBus.Examples.Echo" due to security policies in the configuration file
Aborted
```

:( after that is also not working i found a way to compile the dbus without the X11 Code
with

```
./configure --with-x=no
```

unfortunately it has no effect. Still require X11 to start my applications...
What do i wrong?

but commands like

```
eval 'dbus-launch --auto-syntax' dbus-monitor
```

How can i start my applications without starting X11 i dont need it and i dont want it.
Thank you for your help and time.

kindly regards
oOm

#

Update
i feel a bit silly now  but i found a way to run it without the x11

first you need to start a dbus session daemon

```
dbus-launch
```

this will prompt you your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADRESS

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9rMVHdByuH,guid=10592ff7107f13dd241a02af531ab357
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=2465
```

after that you can launch your c++ application like this

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9rMVHdByuH,guid=10592ff7107f13dd241a02af531ab357" ./server
```

you can registered services with

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-6aT4DZgmA1,guid=b1231a014a7b10e74e04f8ba531abdf9 dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus   --type=method_call --print-reply                 /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

and monitoring the messages with

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-6aT4DZgmA1,guid=b1231a014a7b10e74e04f8ba531abdf9 dbus-monitor
```

but one question is left, how can i do it automatically?

Comment: Sorry for the long Post :)

Comment: Hello Dogan I ended up on your page for I am having similar issue on raspberry pi. dbus-launch command is not found on raspberry pi, I have a headless installation of pi with no X server. How to get dbus-launch package ??

Answer (score 0):

Great post.  You obviously had more diligence than I; I ended up running a display buffer instead.

> *but one question is left, how can i do it automatically?*

Since

```
$dbus-launch
```

outputs the bus info to standard out, did you try just running the program after?  For instance

```
$dbus-launch ./server
```

The dbus-launch man page says:

> You may specify a program to be run; in this case, dbus-launch will
>   launch a session    bus instance, set the appropriate environment
>   variables so the specified program can    find  the bus, and then
>   execute the specified program, with the specified arguments.    See
>   below for examples.
>
> If you launch a program, dbus-launch will not print the information
>   about  the  new    bus to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

> but one question is left, how can i do it automatically?

take a look at [`dbus-launch` manual](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html):

> backticks or the $() construct can be used to read information from
>   **dbus-launch**.